# On using the mean value theorem on this surface integral.

Tags: surface-integrals, electromagnetism

In electrostatics,  the surface of a conductor $S$ is always at a constant potential $\phi _{0}$, where the aforementioned potential is a scalar function $\phi (x,y,z)$ defined as :

$$\phi (\textbf{x}) =\int _{S} \frac{ \sigma(\textbf{x}')}{\vert\lvert  {\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'\lvert\lvert }} da'$$

where $\sigma(\textbf{x})$ is the surface charge density on $S$. As mentioned earlier, the surface of a conductor is equipotential, so if we choose an $\textbf{x}_{0} \in S$, we will have:

$$\phi (\textbf{x}_{0})=\phi_{0} =\int _{S} \frac{ \sigma(\textbf{x}')}{\vert\lvert  {\textbf{x}_{0}-\textbf{x}'\lvert\lvert }} da'=\int _{S}g(\textbf{x}')\sigma (\textbf{x}')da'$$

Is it possible to use the mean value theorem to rewrite the above surface integral  as :

$$\phi_{0} = g(\textbf{x}_{1})\int _{S}\sigma(\textbf{x}')da'$$

where $\textbf{x}_{1}$ is a constant?

Comment: What is $\sigma$? What is $a'$? What are the dimensions here? Note that the mean value theorem only holds in one dimension, i.e., for functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

Comment: @amsmath $\sigma : \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and $da'$ is the area element of the surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it's equivalent to the $dS$ in the first equation of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#targetText=Surface%20integrals%20of%20vector%20fields&targetText=Consider%20a%20vector%20field%20v,the%20result%20is%20a%20vector.) article. $\phi :\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The question above can essentially be restated as: Is there an $(x_{0},y_{0})$ satisfying: $$\int_{D} g(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy=g(x_{0},y_{0})\int_{D}f(x,y)dxdy$$ where $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Is $\sigma$ necessarily positive? I mean, what if its integral was zero?

Comment: @amsmath $\sigma$ could take any real value so long as it it's finite, so we can, for example, have $\sigma (x,y,z) >0$ on some parts of the surface $S$, negative or even null on some other parts, so, yes, there are some functions $\sigma$ that could make the integral null, like for example a $\sigma(x,y,z)$ defined as $-1$ on the south hemisphere of a sphere, and $+1$ on the north hemisphere.

Comment: Then so of course your statement doesn't hold.

Comment: @amsmath I don't really see why not being positive causes problem, see for example the second version of the mean value theorem for integrals, under the "Second mean value theorem for definite integrals" subsection of this 
[article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#cite_note-10#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals), it says,
"If G : [a, b] → R is a monotonic (**not necessarily decreasing and positive**)..."

Comment: Just assume that $\int_S\sigma(x')da' = 0$. You claim that for every $x_0\in S$ there should be some $x_1$ such that $\phi(x_0) = g(x_1)\int_S\sigma(x')da'$. Well, this then only holds if $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: BTW, in your Wiki link check the integral boundaries...

Comment: @amsmath"this then only holds if $\phi (x) =0$ for all $x$, the equality, I believe, implies only $\phi (x_{0})=0$ for all $x_{0} \in S$, which is not really a problem, it just means $\phi$ is null on $S$.

Comment: Oh my... Assume $S = [-1,1]$ and $\sigma(x) = x$, ok? Now, $\phi(x_0) = \int_{-1}^1g(x-x_0)x\,dx$, which is NOT the zero function (e.g., if $g(x) = x$). On the other hand, $g(x_1-x_0)\int_{-1}^1\sigma(x)\,dx = 0$ always.

Comment: @amsmath My apologies, but one important physical aspect of $\phi$ that must be taken into account, mentioned at the very top of the post, is that $\phi(x_{0})$ is always constant on $S$ no matter the chosen $x_{0}$, in your example, the $\sigma$ you've chosen is such that $\phi(x_{0})$ is no longer independent of $x_{0}$, you must choose a $\sigma$ such that $\phi(x) =\mathrm{constant},\, \forall x \in S$.

Comment: Oh, so $\int_S\frac{\sigma(x')}{\|x_0-x'\|}\,da'$ has the same value for all $x_0\in S$?

Comment: @amsmath Yes, exactly.

Comment: I read your question again. So, what is $g$? Is it supposed to depend on $x_0$ or not? And if not, how do you know it exists?

Comment: @amsmath Yes, $g$ depends on $x_{0}$, it is defined as $$g(x)=\frac{1}{||x_{0}-x||}$$. By the way, the $x'$ in $\int_{S} \frac{\sigma(x')}{||x_{0}-x'||}da'$ sweeps the surface $S$ only, $x'\in S$.

Comment: That's clear, Prof. Hilbert. ;-) But so, it will happen that $x_0-x'\notin S$, right? I imagine $S$ to be the unit disk in the $x$-$y$ plane, for example.

Comment: @amsmath I can't really say whether $x_{0}-x' \notin S$, since I don't really know the nature of $x_{0}-x'$, this operation amounts to subtracting two points.

Comment: Well, if $S$ is the unit disk, for example, then $x_0-x'$ runs through the disk with radius 1 around $x_0$. So, it will definitely run out of $S$ (as long as $x_0\neq 0$)

Comment: @amsmath, Sorry but I still don't understand what you mean by $x_{0}-x'$, is it $|x_{0}-x'|$? Both $x_{0}$ and $x'$ belong to the surface $S$.

Comment: Yes, both belong to $S$ (which in my example is the unit disk). Assume $x_0 = (\frac 12,0,0)$. Now, for $x' = (s,0,0)$ with $s<-\frac 12$ we have $x_0-x' = (\frac 12-s,0,0)\notin S$ because $\frac 12-s > 1$.

Comment: What does the constancy of $\phi$ imply for $\sigma$? I don't see it.

Comment: @amsmath Let us simplify the problem, and suppose we have one type  only of $\sigma$ over $S$, either strictly positive, or strictly negative. The hypothesis would hold in this case, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\sigma > 0$ and that the surface $S$ is compact. Then the function $g(y) = \frac 1{\|x_0-y\|}$ is continuous outside of any small neighborhood of $x_0$ and thus has and attains a minimum $c>0$ there. Since $g(y)$ is extremely large in small neighborhoods of $x_0$ we conclude that the image of $g$ on $S\setminus\{x_0\}$ equals $[c,\infty)$. In particular, $g(y)\ge c$ for all $y\in S$. This implies $g(y)\sigma(y)\ge c\sigma(y)$ for all $y\in S$ and thus $\int_S g(y)\sigma(y)\,da'\ge cI$, where $I := \int_S\sigma(y)\,da'$. Thus, $\frac 1I\int_S g(y)\sigma(y)\,da'\ge c$ and $g$ attains this value, i.e., there exists $x_1\in S$ such that $g(x_1) = \frac 1I\int_S g(y)\sigma(y)\,da'$, which was the claim.

Comment: Simple and classy, thanks!